# How to avoid the use of raw type and use generics instead when the type is unknown?

Tags: java, events, generics, raw-types

I have a generic interface for a handler:

```
public interface EventHandler<T> {

     boolean handleEvent(T message);
}
```

You can implement this interface and process `T message`. You have to pass an instance of your implementation to an `EventDispatcher` instance. The class stores internally multiple `EventHandler` instances of various types.

At some point an event is triggered and the `EventDispatcher` instance calls the corresponding `EventHandler`'s `handleEvent()` method and passes a message that is the same type as the `EventHandler`. The problem is that I don't know which is the exact type, but I am sure that the `T message` I'm passing to the `EventHandler` instance have the same "T".

The way I make this call uses raw types and works:

```
EventHandler handler = getHandler();
Object message = getMessage();
handler.handleEvent(message);
```

,but I get the warning "Unchecked call to 'handleEvent(T)' as a member of raw type 'EventHandler'".

Is it possible to use generics to avoid the warning?

One possible solution I have thought of is to make a generic wrapper method:

```
private <T> boolean handleEventGeneric(EventHandler<T> handler, T message) {
    return handler.handleEvent(message);
}
```

and use it:

```
EventHandler handler = getHandler();
Object message = getMessage();
handleEventGeneric(action.eventHandler, message);
```

But I don't like the fact that I have to make a wrapper method. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: That second code snippet is still using raw types.

Comment: But it sounds like an unsolvable problem; you're trying to use compile-time type safety based on information that's only available at run-time.

Comment: The last code sample does not use `handler` variable. Is there a mistake? Also please provide the signatures of `getHandler()` and `getMessage()` methods.

Comment: I think your problem is `getMessage()`. Why does it return `Object`?

Comment: @ Oliver Charlesworth You are right. It still uses raw types, but I don't get a compiler warning. Indeed, what you said about trying to use compile-time safety based on run-time information seems to be the case here. I just wanted to make sure that there isn't another alternative.

Comment: @RealSkeptic `getMessage()` returns `Object` because internally it stores different types of messages that are stored in a list of `Object`s. The same goes for `getHandler()`.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev the last code sample uses `handler` using the generic method `handleEventGeneric()`.

Comment: Then the question is why the list is a list of Objects. You need to go further and further back to the root cause - you're using `Object` where you shouldn't. Are the messages standard Java types like `Integer`, `String`, `List` etc., or your own classes?

Comment: @RealSkeptic The messages could be whatever type the "user" of the EventHandler wants. So, I have to store them in a list of Objects.

Comment: But is it a type from the standard library or a new type?

Comment: @Petrakeas Shouldn't you still get a warning when you call `handleEventGeneric` and pass it raw types? I am not sure how you managed to suppress the warning. All you are doing is transferring it from one part of your code to another.

Comment: @Cheta Kinger Yes, seems like I'm propagating the problem later on, but the compiler doesn't produce a warning in this case. Doesn't really make a difference since I'm doing the same thing anyway.

Comment: @RealSkeptic It could be a new type. But even if it was a type from the standard library, I don't see why it changes the semantics of the problem, which as Oliver Charlesworth stated is that I'm trying to use compile-time type safety based on information that's only available at run-time.

Comment: Simply, if it is a type you can control, you can create an interface that all message objects have to implement.

Comment: What type does `getHandler()` return? If it returns `EventHandler`, that's already a raw type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to remove this warning (or at least not without `@SuppressWarning`). The only way to get rid of it is by doing 2 things:

1. Making your code type proof: so basically if the invoking code does not use raw type, you are type safe or the invoking code is using rawtypes and it it's fault if the code end up being no type safe
2. Add the `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` on your code.

The warning is there so that you can easily identify where you have a weakness in terms of type safety, in your code. If you use the annotation correctly, then your code is safe and you're sure of not getting any unpleasant `ClassCastException`, unless you willingly added an `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` in a place where you are actually not all that sure that the type is safe.

See some demo code illustrating my point:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestGenerics {

    private Map<Class<?>, EventHandler<?>> handlers = new HashMap<Class<?>, TestGenerics.EventHandler<?>>();

    public interface EventHandler<T> {

        boolean handleEvent(T message);
    }

    // Here you force the invoker to provide the correct type of event handler
    // with the given type of klass
    // If he wants to make this fail, then he will have to use rawtype
    public <T> void registerHandler(Class<T> klass, EventHandler<T> handler) {
        handlers.put(klass, handler);
    }

    public <T> void handle(T message) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Here you can add this annotation since you are forcing any invoker to provide a correct EventHandler
        EventHandler<T> handler = (EventHandler<T>) handlers.get(message.getClass());
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.handleEvent(message);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestGenerics test = new TestGenerics();
        test.registerHandler(Long.class, new EventHandler<Long>() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleEvent(Long message) {
                System.out.println("Received a long " + message);
                return true;
            }
        });
        // Here I use raw type but this also means that I created a weak spot in
        // terms of type safety
        EventHandler handler2 = new EventHandler<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleEvent(String message) {
                System.out.println("THis will never print " + message);
                return false;
            }
        };
        test.registerHandler(Integer.class, handler2); // This is where the
                                                        // problem comes from
        test.handle(3L); // OK
        test.handle(1); // ClassCastException

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [warning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) suggest you have genric type safety problem, which is very easy to handle with proper diamond operator before addressing the inherited generic types with in other class.
For instance

```html
public class Parent<R, V> {
...
    public class Child<T, S extends Number> {
    ...
    }
}
```

Generic type safe declaring

```
  <T, S extends Number> Parent<R, V>.Child<T, S> someMethodCall(...)
```

The `R, V` in provided declaration are generic types that referenced with in class/interface which the `someMethod` exist, in general they can even specify with in method as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this:

```
EventHandler<Object> handler = getHandler();
Object message = getMessage();
handler.handleEvent(message);
```

It's not safe, but no less safe than what you have now.

Comment: Actually, this is very wrong. This is exactly what you should not do. Replace this snippet with something you are more used to like `List<Object> list = getList(); list.add("MyString");` where you have `public List getList() { return some List<Integer> };` you will end up with heap pollution because you are adding a String to a List of Integer.